# Как добавить массив с листом заказа к массиву сделок в Laravel?

Tags: laravel

Делаю API. Есть таблица Deals сделал модель с формированием массива и контроллер с простейшим выводом массива. Но у сделок иногда имеется лист состава сделки с товарами, который находится в таблице products_order_list и связаны между собой по id_deals (таблица deals) и id_connection (таблица products_order_list), так же сделана модель и контроллер с простейшим выводом массива.

**Как мне добавить к массиву сделки, массив с листом состава сделки по id_deals?** И где это лучше делать?

Пример Model (такой же и у products_order_list):

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DealsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "deals";
    public  $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        "id_deals", "number_deals"
    ];
    
}
```

Контроллер:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Deals;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\DealsModel;

use Validator;

class DealsController extends Controller
{
    public function deals(){
        return response()->json(DealsModel::paginate(30), 200);
    }
    public function dealsById($id){
        
        $deals = DealsModel::find($id); 
        if( is_null($deals)) {
            return response()->json(['erroe' => true, 'message' => 'Not found'], 404);
        }
        return response()->json($deals, 200);
    }
}
```

Пробовал так:

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DealsModel extends Model
{
    protected $table = "deals";
    public  $timestamps = false;
    protected $fillable = [
        "id_deals", "number_deals", "products_order_list" => products_order_list::where('id_connection', 'id_deals')->get()
    ];
    
}
```

Comment: Ты серьезно в массиве `$fillable` пытаешься сделать запрос???

Comment: @МаксимК да я не шарю в Laravel только разбираюсь. Уже понял тупость сделал. Если ты видишь, что человек сделал неправильно, то укажи на это и поправь в нужном направлении, а то выделываешься сидишь отвечая вопросом на вопрос!

Comment: Я не хотел тебя обидеть. Но согласись, что ты задумался и возможно сам попытался разобраться, почему это "сделал тупость". Конкретно в этой конструкции нет отношения к фреймворку, а только к php. Дело в том, что нельзя при объявлении свойства класса выполнять какие-либо функции или методы. При определении свойства можно указать только статические значения.

Comment: К сожалению при быстом просмотре твоего вопроса, я его не понял. Покажи структуру таблиц, что за поле `id_deals`? Как говорится, хорошо заданный вопрос - уже половина ответа

Comment: @МаксимК id_deals обычное поле id, почему-то так его назвал. Это просто ID сделки в базе. Мне по сути надо к массиву сделки добавить массив товаров которые добавлены в эту сделку по id сделки они связаны.

Comment: Пожалуйста, почитай эти рекомендации по написанию кода https://github.com/alexeymezenin/laravel-best-practices/blob/master/russian.md 
Это не относится к вопросу, но это тебе очень поможет писать понятный код.

Comment: И опять повторюсь: добавь к вопросу структуру таблиц, а также классы своих моделей. Мне нужно увидеть, как ты организовал связь многие-ко-многим (m2m). Но исходя из комментариев, ты организовал связь один-ко-многим, что скорее всего неверно в данном случае. И подскажи, пожалуйста, ты с документацией ознакомился? даже та отсталая русскоязычная документация очень полезна